# Why proximal gradient is a special case of sub-gradient?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, convex

While I was learning proximal gradient descent methods, I saw many similar statements as below:

$$p=prox_f(x) \Longleftrightarrow x-p \in \partial f(p) $$

for example, `Definition` section from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_method) and page 3-7 of [this slide](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture18.pdf).

I know how to go from right side to left side of above statement, but how about the opposite direction?

Comment: Hi there and welcome. Type these out. It's the law on and around this site. – *Reviewer*

Comment: p. 131 of Parikh and Boyd "Proximal Algorithms" https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf , which in turn references the famous book,Rockafellar "Convex Analysis"/

Comment: Or look on the bottom of p 3 of https://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_notes.pdf .

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you, @MarkL.Stone! After reading the materials, I found I misunderstood the addition and subtraction between sets/points.

Comment: You can write up your own answer and accept it to close out this question.